# How to compute mean by interval of values?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns:

```
   A     B
   1     5
   2     4
   1     3
   2     2
   3     5
```

What I need is to compute the mean for all values in B for certain class from A:
for instance,  compute mean for all values from B (that only correspond between 0 and 2 from A) and same for 2-4
so my class from A   0-2  2-4  4-6

any idea?

Comment: You can use `cut` to create a grouping variable and then get the `mean` of 'B'

Comment: Could you show how pls and I also want to plot the mean with the classes?

Comment: In the example showed, A don't have a value that falls betweeen 4-6.  What do you want to fill for the `mean` of 'B' for those cases?

Comment: Try `df1$A1 <-  cut(df1$A, breaks=c(0,2,4,6));tapply(df1$B, df1$A1, FUN= mean)`

Comment: Try the code posted above.

Comment: You could try `barplot(tapply(df1$B, df1$A1, FUN= mean))`

Comment: Are your intervals inclusive?  In other words, the second line where A is 2, should that B value be included in both the interval from 0-2 and from 2-4 or should it be in only one of those?  If only one, the solution from @akrun is exactly what you need.  If both, a different approach is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on rather your intervals are inclusive or not (is the second line included in both the 0-2 interval and the 2-4 interval, or just one of these).

If the intervals are not closed (intervals are at least half-open) and adjacent, @akrun gave the best approach in a comment by using the `cut` function to create a new grouping factor as `cut(df$A, breaks=2*(0:3))` and then using tapply to apply the mean based on this using `tapply(df$B,cut(df$A, breaks=2*0:3,FUN=mean)`.  This approach will not handle cases where you need closed intervals, or points may fall in multiple intervals.  It also will not give you a value for intervals in which no points fall (which may or may not be desired).  The intervals will have to be adjacent as well.

---

The following approach allows arbitrary intervals, and by default, identifies intervals in which no points fall.  Points are allowed to fall in more than one interval.

```
df<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,1,2,3),B=c(5,4,3,2,5))
cuts<-matrix(c(0,2,2,4,4,6),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

Here, the **cuts** matrix will contain the actual interval boundaries:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    2
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    4    6
```

Now we write function that selects elements in the interval<sup>**†**</sup>

```
cls<-function(vals,cat) {(vals>=cat[1]&vals<=cat[2])}
```

Here **cls** expects to receive a vector of values and a vector giving the upper and lower boundaries of an interval.  It returns a boolean vector indicating if the value is in the interval or not.  For example, `cls(df$A,c(0,2))` produces

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

telling us that all but the last value of A is in the interval from 0 to 2.

Finally, we can find the mean of the B values for each interval like so,<sup>**‡**</sup>

```
apply(cuts,1,function(x){mean(df$B[cls(df$A,x)])})
```

This processes each row in the **cuts** matrix (the 1 as the second option means by rows), and computes the mean of the B values corresponding to A values in the interval specified by that row (`df$B[cls(df$A,x)]` uses our **cls** function to find the A values in the interval specified by x and then selects the B values corresponding to this - the ones where the returned value is *TRUE* ).

The result is

```
[1] 3.500000 3.666667      NaN
```

This tells us the the mean of the B values corresponding to A values from 0 to 2 is 3.5, the mean of the B values corresponding to A values from 2 to 4 is 3 and 2/3, and there are no B values corresponding to A values from 4 to 6 (as there are no such A values).

---

<sup>**†**</sup> If a half-open is desired, it is easy to modify **cls** for such.  If we wish to exclude the right boundary, we can use

```
cls<-function(vals,cat) {(vals>=cat[1]&vals<cat[2])}
```

and if we wish to exclude the lower boundary, we can use

```
cls<-function(vals,cat) {(vals>cat[1]&vals<=cat[2])}
```

or using strictly open intervals, we can do

```
cls<-function(vals,cat) {(vals>cat[1]&vals<cat[2])}
```

However, in these cases, using the built-in `cut` function may be best.

---

<sup>**‡**</sup> If you don't want to create the function **cls**, the entire selection can be in-lined like

```
apply(cuts,1,function(x){mean(df$B[df$A>=x[1]&df$A<=x[2]])})
```

or, eliminating the need for the **cuts** variable as well,

```
apply(matrix(c(0,2,2,4,4,6),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE),1,function(x){mean(df$B[df$A>=x[1]&df$A<=x[2]])})
```

Answer (score -1):

The tapply function is what you need.

    `tapply(df$B, df$A, mean)`

should do the trick. There are more efficient ways to do this for bigger data. Also have a look at group_by and summarize in dplyr.